# How to optimize this complex query?

Tags: mysql, sql

How i can optimize this query? for now it's executing in 0.0100 second.

```
SELECT comments.comment_content, comments.comment_votes, comments.comment_date,
  users.user_login, users.user_level, users.user_avatar_source, 
  groups.group_safename 
FROM comments
LEFT JOIN links ON comment_link_id=link_id 
LEFT JOIN users ON comment_user_id=user_id
LEFT JOIN groups ON comment_group_id=link_group_id 
WHERE comment_status='published' AND link_status='published' 
ORDER BY comment_id DESC
```

EXPLAIN output:

[image]

Indexes:

Comment:

[image]

Users:

[image]

Groups:

[image]

Comment: Add indexes, there are none in the last two joins.

Comment: you need indexes on `link_id ,comment_user_id,user_id,comment_group_id and link_group_id`

Comment: It's executing in 0.01 seconds?  How awful.  Time to change your schema, buy new hardware and rewrite your application!  Knuth clearly had no idea what he was talking about when he said "*premature optimisation is the root of all evil*".

Comment: $M Khalid Junaid but i have them :) @eggyal It's executing in 0.01 seconds on a empty dev server, on my production node it takes up to 0.200 seconds so yeah, 200 miliseconds for one query is a problem for me.

Comment: Perhaps you could then show the `EXPLAIN` plan from your production node?  The dev tables contain only 13, 2 and 1 records respectively which makes diagnosing the exact problem somewhat difficult (the cardinality of many indexes is such that MySQL simply ignores them).

Comment: As an aside, this is also *far* from a "complex" query.  In fact, it's about as simple as SQL gets.

Comment: Hm... thanks, i guess? I'm fairy new to MySQL i though it was complex :) I'll add EXPLAIN output from my production server when i'll be back in home. (4 hours)

Comment: Hey @eggyal, lighten up bro. We've all been beginners. It's true that a 10ms query is pretty fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub-twenty-millisecond query times aren't usually considered to be slow.  As some folks have mentioned in the comments, it will be necessary for you to redo your optimization when your tables get larger, because MySQL's optimizer (and optimizers for other RDMSs) makes decisions based on index size.

I recommend you always qualify your column names in JOIN clauses with table names or aliases.  For example, you will gain clarity and maintainability by using a style like this:

```
FROM comments AS c
LEFT JOIN links AS L ON c.comment_link_id=L.link_id 
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON c.comment_user_id=u.user_id
LEFT JOIN groups AS g ON c.comment_group_id=g.link_group_id
```

This query selects a fairly broad subset of your tables, so it will run slower the larger your tables are. That's inevitable unless you can narrow the subset somehow.

Are the columns you're using for `JOIN ... ON` operations all declared `NOT NULL`? They should be.

Looking at how you are using the `groups` table: You're joining on `link_group_id` and retrieving `group_safename`.  So, try a compound covering index on `(link_group_id,group_safename)`. At a minimum, index `link_group_id`.

The `users` table: You've already got an index on `user_id`. When your tables get bigger a compound covering index on `(user_id, user_login, user_level, user_avatar_source)` may help. But that's a low-priority thing to try.

The `links` table: You're using `link_status` and `link_id`.  Your `LEFT JOIN` for this table should be a plain inner `JOIN` because one of its columns shows up in your `WHERE` clause.  If `link_status` can be `NOT NULL` in your application make sure it is declared that way.  Then try a compound index on `(link_status, link_id)`.

The `comments` table: You have no index on `comment_status` as far as I can see.  Try adding one.

Then put a bunch of data in your tables, run `OPTIMIZE LOCAL TABLE` for each table, then try your query with EXPLAIN again.